# Set dynamic value on EpicEditor

Tags: javascript, html, editor, epiceditor

I am using a [EpicEditor](http://epiceditor.com/). Below is the code through which I am initializing by epiceditor:

```
 var opts = {
    container: 'epiceditor',
    textarea: null,
    theme: {
        base: '/themes/base/epiceditor.css',
        preview: '/themes/preview/github.css',
        editor: '/themes/editor/epic-light.css'
    },
    basePath: '/epiceditor',
    clientSideStorage: false
}
var editor = new EpicEditor(opts);
editor.load();
```

I have some value which I am fetching from database and want to show on the epicedior. I am new to the epicEditor and no idea how to do that. Can somebody help me on this! Any expert on EpicEditor!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set "textarea" property to the textarea field id from where you want to sync contents to EpicEditor.

I have my configuration something like this:

```
var opts = {
    container: 'epiceditor',
    textarea: null,
    basePath: 'epiceditor',
    clientSideStorage: true,
    localStorageName: 'epiceditor',
    useNativeFullscreen: true,
    parser: marked,
    file: {
        name: 'epiceditor',
        defaultContent: '',
        autoSave: 100
    },
    theme: {
        base: '/themes/base/epiceditor.css',
        preview: '/themes/preview/preview-dark.css',
        editor: '/themes/editor/epic-dark.css'
    },
    button: {
        preview: true,
        fullscreen: true
    },
    focusOnLoad: false,
    shortcut: {
        modifier: 18,
        fullscreen: 70,
        preview: 80
    },
    string: {
        togglePreview: 'Toggle Preview Mode',
        toggleEdit: 'Toggle Edit Mode',
        toggleFullscreen: 'Enter Fullscreen'
    }
}
var editor = new EpicEditor(opts);
```

You can check more APIs [here](http://epiceditor.com/).

Comment: Thanks Manish! That's perfect!